# Gameobjects not spawning after i destroy them (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a first version of a game with unity, but the trees wont keep spawning after i have destroyed the tree amount to less than 5. In unity when i run the game it displays the tree amount and when it reaches 5 it stops spawning them but if i destroy one it wont spawn a new one even tho the tree amount is less than 5.

Also if i keep destroying them so there is always just two trees then it keeps spawning. But whenever it reaches 5 then it stops.

I have two scripts:

This is the one where if i click the tree it destroys it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Harvest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tree;
    public int treeScore;
    public void AddTreeScore()
    {
        treeScore++;
    }

    private Spawner spawnerScript;
    void Start()
    {
        spawnerScript = FindObjectOfType<Spawner>();
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GameObject.Destroy(tree);
        spawnerScript.treeAmount--;
        AddTreeScore();
        Debug.Log(treeScore);
        

    }


}
```

And this is everything else.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tree;

    public int treeAmount;

    public float spawnRate = 1f;

    public bool canSpawn = true;

    public int maxAmount = 5;

    private IEnumerator Spawning()
    {
        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);

        while (canSpawn == true)
        {
            yield return wait;
            
            Vector2 randomSpawnPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(-10, 11), Random.Range(-4, 5));
            Instantiate(tree, randomSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            AddTreeAmount();

            if (treeAmount >= maxAmount)
            {
                canSpawn = false;
                
            }
            if( treeAmount < maxAmount)
            {
                canSpawn = true;
            }
            

        }
    }
    void AddTreeAmount()
    {
        treeAmount++;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Spawning());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I also tried setting the `spawnRate` to `0f;` and then back to `1f;`, but that did not work. It showed in unity that the `spawnRate` went to 0 but it kept still spawning them.

I think i have to set the `canSpawn` back to true some other way. Or is there more errors or mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this loop.

```
while (canSpawn == true)
{
    yield return wait;
    
    Vector2 randomSpawnPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(-10, 11), Random.Range(-4, 5));
    Instantiate(tree, randomSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    AddTreeAmount();

    if (treeAmount >= maxAmount)
    {
        canSpawn = false;
        
    }
    if( treeAmount < maxAmount)
    {
            canSpawn = true;
    }
}
```

Your if statement checks if our tree count is over the max amout allowed and if it is then canSpawn is set to false. Your loop only runs when canSpawn is true. So if canSpawn ever becomes false the loop stops executing and you are never able to reach the code that can set it true again. And the loop is only ever started once because its triggered in Start.

The solution is to make the loop infinite so it only ends when your program ends. Simply use an if statement with your condition that allows your spawn to happen around the part that spawns the next tree rather than a while condition. This means you don't break out of the loop while until your game has ended or you intentionally break out of it with the `break` keyword.

```
WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);

while (true)
{
    yield return wait;

    if (treeAmount >= maxAmount)
    {
       canSpawn = false;
    }
    else
    {
        canSpawn = true;
    }

    if(canSpawn)
    {
        Vector2 randomSpawnPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(-10, 11), Random.Range(-4, 5));
        Instantiate(tree, randomSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        AddTreeAmount();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a simple fix :D

Comment: @Samurai6219 while this answers the issue in a very similar way as my answer note that an infinite loop routine runs forever putting unnecessary load into the update call every frame. It is very tiny of course but my previous solution actually avoids that by running the routine only when it is actually required ;)

Comment: Yes. My initial solution was to make it more event driven or to move the whole thing into update for simplicity, but I thought I had better keep it as close to the original code as possible in the event there are other constraints to satisfy. Using a coroutine in the first place seemed like a non-obvious choice compared to other simpler solutions so I didn't want to just gut it. For what it's worth I personally like @derHugo 's solution more if I was doing this from scratch.

Comment: @Samurai6219 Although this seems to have worked for you before my edit, I have edited for clarity. The loop previously wasn't infinite in the second code block due to have a condition in the while.

Comment: Oh yeah, so basically "canSpawn" is useless? I tried Hugo's way also, it did work but i could not understand nothing. As a newbie, your's made a little bit more sense.

Comment: @Samurai6219 It's not useless but it should only be used in the if condition here, not the loop. If you use it in this particular loop you can end your loop with no way to get back into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your coroutine `Spawning` runs exactly once - at the beginning of the game.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Spawning());
}
```

Once `canSpawn = false;` is reached it will never run again.

Instead you could use a field for tracking if an instance of that routine is already running and if not run a new one like e.g.

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // in general for things you only set up via the Inspector
    // you should use private o avoid other classes to modify them (Encapsulation)
    [SerializeField] private GameObject tree;
    [SerializeField] private float spawnRate = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private int maxAmount = 5;

    // backing field for treeAmount
    private int _treeAmount;

    // keeps track whether a Spawning routine is already running
    private bool spawning;

    public int treeAmount
    {
        get => _treeAmount;
        set 
        {
            // this is executed whenever a value is assigned

            _treeAmount = value;
            RunSpawningRoutine();
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
         RunSpawningRoutine();
    }

    private void RunSpawningRoutine()
    {
        // if already spawning ignore
        if(spawning) return;

        StartCoroutine(Spawning());
    }

    private IEnumerator Spawning()
    {
        // just in case double safety for blocking concurrent routines
        if(spawning) yield break;

        // block other routines from running (see above)
        spawning = true;

        // simpler and cleaner loop condition
        while (treeAmount < maxAmount)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
            
            // generally note that this does not prevent two trees spawning in the same spot
            var randomSpawnPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(-10, 11), Random.Range(-4, 5));
            Instantiate(tree, randomSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            treeAmount++;
        }

        // allow a next routine to start
        spawning = false;
    }
}
```

This way whenever a value is assigned to `treeAmount` it will kickoff `RunSpawningRoutine`. Here you will check whether a routine is already running in which case you don't have to do anything, but if not it will start a new routine.

---

Follow up for the random position overlaps:

That's not straight forward the way you have it right now as there is no track of existing or destroyed/removed trees.

You could though have a dedicated component

```
public class Tree : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static readonly HashSet<Tree> Instances = new ();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

This way every existing instance of `Tree` will automatically register and remove itself to and from `Instances`.

Then in your spawning you can keep re-creating new random positions in case one is already taken like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...


while (treeAmount < maxAmount)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
    
    // generally note that this does not prevent two trees spawning in the same spot
    Vector3 randomSpawnPos;
    do
    {
        randomSpawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10, 11), Random.Range(-4, 5));
    } 
    // you could implement the following also without Linq using a foreach loop
    // but this is one of the cases where Linq just is way more beautiful to read and write ;)
    while(Tree.Instances.Any(tree => tree.transform.position == randomSpawnPos));

    Instantiate(tree, randomSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    treeAmount++;
}
```

Comment: Well at least now it seems to work great. Looks like gibberish to me, but maybe ill understand it some day. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: "generally note that this does not prevent two trees spawning in the same spot" Is there a quick and easy way to do that? Not asking you to do that, just wanted to know to look up information myself.

Comment: @Samurai6219 see update at the bottom

Comment: I might add this a bit later if the overlapping becomes a problem, but thank a lot again!